# oracle client in alpine linux

Tags: oracle, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Oracle Client in Alpine Linux (Container)

Steps which I have followed

1) Downloaded https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/195000/oracle-instantclient19.5-basic-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
This is oracle basic rpm

2) Downloaded https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/195000/oracle-instantclient19.5-sqlplus-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

This is sqlplus rpm

3) following commands in Alpine container

apk update && apk add wget unzip libaio rpm alien

rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient19.5-basic-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient19.5-sqlplus-19.5.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm

I am not able to install oracle client in Alpine Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any error messages? Whats not working?

Comment: when I am trying to run sqlplus, I am getting the message /bin/sh sqlplus command not found ??

Comment: error: Failed to resolve symbol ima_hooks: Symbol not found: nspr_use_zone_allocator

Comment: lchmod (file attributes) error: Not supported
  instantclient_19_6/libclntsh.so.10.1 -> libclntsh.so.19.1